# Signin.status won't change to 'OK'

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-signin

I am trying to let people signin into my Google Action. Found the sample code, tried it but I can't get it to work. Signin.status is 'undefined' in the logs.

What am I doing wrong?

```
'use strict';

const {dialogflow, Carousel, BrowseCarousel, BrowseCarouselItem, 
Image, SimpleResponse, Confirmation, Option, option, Suggestions, 
SignIn} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({
    clientId: '<MYCLIENTID>',
  });





//-----------------------INTENT 0: WELCOME -------------------------------------------
app.intent("Default Welcome Intent", (conv, input) => {

conv.add('Welcome. Sign in? ')
})


//-----------------------INTENT 1: Welcome -> yes  -------------------------------------------
app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', conv => {
    conv.add(new SignIn('To get your data.'))
  })


//-----------------------INTENT 2: LINKING CHECK -------------------------------------------
app.intent("Linking Check", (conv, params, signin) => {
    console.log(signin + ' ' + signin.status )
    if (signin.status !== 'OK') {
        conv.close('It's not possible to use this app without signing in. Goodbye!');
    } else {
    const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;
    conv.add(`I got your account details, ${payload.name}. What do you want to do next?`);
    }
})


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I would expect a properly working signin flow. But instead of that, the assistant won't let me acces intent 1, but repeats intent 0 after replying 'yes' to the welcome intent.

If I invoke intent 2, it provides me with: 'It's not possible to use this app without signing in. Goodbye!', so the signin.status is not 'OK'. 
In the logs, the signin.status if 'undefined'.

Pictures:

Overview
[image: Overview]

Intent 0
[image: Intent 0]
[image: Intent 0]

Intent 1
[image: Intent 1]
[image: Intent 1]

Intent 2
[image: Intent 2]

Comment: Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55600430/edit) to show screen shots of each of the Intents in your Dialogflow UI? The training phrases and events are the most important sections to see.

Comment: I've updated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mostly on the right track, but it looks like there are a few issues that may be causing you problems:

- Intent 1 is never triggered because it is expecting the `Google Assistant Sign In` event. This event is only triggered *after* the user goes through the sign-in process. Since the code in the Intent Handler is supposed to *start* the sign-in process, this never gets called.
- Similarly, Intent 2 doesn't have this event. So it isn't triggered when sign-in finishes. Furthermore, the `signin` parameter isn't set for every call - just for the one when sign-in finishes.

If you move where the event is handled, you should get results that work a bit better.